# MATLAB: mean(X(Y == y, :));

Tags: matlab, mean

Looking over some MATLAB code related to multivariate Gaussian distributions and I come across this line:

```
params.means(k, :) = mean(X(Y == y, :));
```

Looking at the MATLAB documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html, my assumption is that it calculates the mean over the matrix X in the first dimension (the column). What I don't see is the parentheses that comes after. Is this a conditional probability (where Y = y)? Can someone point me to some documentation where this is explained?

Comment: Y==y returns a matrix of the same size as Y or y (depending on which one is scalar).  entries are 1 if that entry equals the scalar y and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How does that relate to the combination with X. Because the actual matrix that is returned isn't just composed of 1's and 0's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpacked, this single line might look like:

```
row_indices = find(Y==y);
new_X = X(row_indices,:);
params.means(k,:) = mean(new_X);
```

So, as you can see, the `Y==y` is simply being used to find a subset of X over which the mean is taken.

Given that you said that this was for computing multivariate Gaussian distributions, I bet that X and Y are paired sets of data.  I bet that the code is looping (using the variable `k`) over different values `y`.  So, it finds all of the `Y` equal to `y` and then calculates the mean of the `X` values that correspond to those `Y` values.

Comment: And you would have won the bet! :D Thanks a ton, your explanation and code sample hits it right on the head.